# Android SharedPreference JSON not being accessed

Tags: android

I am using volley to send a http request to yahoo's weather API like this:

```
        public Object requestData(String url) {
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                null,
                new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                     String responseList = response.toString();
                   cityList.edit().putString(String.valueOf(i), responseList);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
        return null;
    }
```

As you can see, I am putting the response to this inside a sharedpreference I declared as "citylist"
:

```
      cityList = getSharedPreferences(String.valueOf(i), MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I then access this response inside the sharedpreference like this:

```
       String mResponse = cityList.getString(String.valueOf(i), "");
                Log.d("log", mResponse);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(mResponse);
                    JSONObject response = jsonObj.getJSONObject("query");
                    createdCity.temperature = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("item").optJSONObject("condition").getInt("temp");
                    createdCity.conditions = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("item").optJSONObject("condition").getString("text");
                    createdCity.town = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("location").getString("city");
                    createdCity.country = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("location").getString("country");
                    createdCity.state = response.optJSONObject("results").optJSONObject("channel").optJSONObject("location").getString("region");
                   Log.d("log", String.valueOf(createdCity.town));
                    cities.add(createdCity);
                    addMenuItemInNavMenuDrawer();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The problem is that "log" isn't outputting anything. The only information I'm getting from the logcat is:

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

How can I go about fixing my issue? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can use something like http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ to debug and see what is the exact value being stored in SharedPreferences

Comment: (1) why are you using `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `StringRequest` if you want the `String` representation of the `JSON` data that the Yahoo Weather API returns. (2) what is the value of "i" in `String.valueOf(i)`? (3) and most important...Are you certain, that `responseList` actually contains a JSON string?

Comment: @Barns (1) I changed my volley request to StringRequest (2) String.valueof(i) is simply an index of how many requests have been made, starting at 0 obviously (3) I changed cityList to just response so that the response gets directly placed into the sharedpreference. I am still get the same error in my logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you committing after editing the preference? Based on your response, you might as well use `apply()` as it does things asynchronously.

If you are sure that the commit won't affect the main thread, you can use `cityList.commit()` or safely use `cityList.apply()`. But you need to do either of these two or else the changes are not written to the disk which is the reason you are not able to retrieve the data.

This link should help:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

Comment: Although I made a few changes here and there, This was definitely my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please accept and upvote if the answere resolved your issue.

Comment: says I don’t have the reputation or something?

Comment: How did I not see that he forgot to add `commit()` or `apply()`?  Good catch!